# Increment counter with name based on input

Tags: macros, counters

I have different counters, and I want to increment them. After I do not want to increment them separately, I wanted to write a macro which does that for me, depending on the input. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcounter{countera}
\newcounter{counterb}
\newcommand{\toC}[1]{
    \stepcounter{%
        \expandafter\csname counter#1\endcsname%
        }
}
\begin{document}
\toC{a}
\end{document}
```

When I now want to increment counter `countera`, I just want to call `\toC{a}` instead of `\stepcounter{countera}`. By using the code above, I get a lot of errors, such as `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`, `! Extra \endcsname.` and `! LaTeX Error: No counter '\countera ' defined.` The macro `\toC{}` will be expanded later, thus I would prefer to keep its structure like this, if possible. Why do I get those errors?

Comment: There's no need to use `\csname counter#1\endcsname` here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcounter{countera}
\newcounter{counterb}
\newcommand{\toC}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{%
    counter#1%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\toC{a}
\toC{b}

\thecountera

\thecounterb

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe also include how to use \thecounter#1 directly afterwards? Furthermore I had to notice that the `%` are absolutely necessary here, otherwise I get errors...

Comment: Problem solved, had to use `\expandafter\csname thecounter#1\endcsname%` there.

Comment: @arc_lupus: Ok, you solved it, but `\csname thecounter#1\endcsname` wasn't in your question anyways;-)